# Parametrization of $x^2-y^2=1$; Why does the following only cover the "right-hand side"?

Tags: functions, parametric, parametrization

I have the parabola $x^2-y^2=1$. I am asked to first show that $\cosh(t)=x,\sinh(t)=y$ parameterizes the curve.

This, I have done; substituting to the implicit function expression gives $1$.

But I guess I am missing something from the concept as I cannot understand the following statement.

> This parametrization covers only the right-hand side of $x^2-y^2=1$ because $\cosh(t)$ is always positive.

I don't see how $\cosh(t)$ always positive $=$ "covers only right-hand side of the function(graph)".

Can someone explain to me why? I simply don't understand why not cover the entire parabola with this particular parametrization.

Comment: $x=\cosh(t)>0$ means you only get positive $x$. There's no way to get negative $x$ points, so you only cover right hand side

Comment: The curve is a hyperbola. That's why $\cosh t$, $\sinh t$ are called hyperbolic functions.